# HackerRank: LIKE vs REGEXP

Tags: mysql, sql

Working through [Weather Observation Station 6](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-6) on hackerRank, and I can't understand why the former code works but the latter does not. Doesn't my like clause detect a first letter starting with a vowel and then any wildcards following it? Just as the regexp anchors at the beginning of the string and checks that the first character is a vowel. Why aren't they equivalent?..

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiou]%';
```

vs.

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE city REGEXP '^[aeiou]';
```

Comment: Why would they be equivalent? `[aeiou]` in `regexp` means "one of a,e,i,o or u" in `like` it means "match [aeiou] literally"

Comment: Standard SQL's `LIKE'  doesn't support ranges of characters, this is a T-SQL extension.

Comment: What @dnoeth says is correct, though the OP is using a set rather than a range this is still TSQL. (Syntax for a range would be `[0-9]` for example)

Answer (score 2):

`like` doesn't work that way. it looks for a string  starting with `[aeiou]` per your query.

To get the values starting with a vowel using `like`, you should do

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY LIKE 'a%' or city like 'e%' or city like 'i%' or city like 'o%'
or city like 'u%'
```

Edit:

As mentioned in the comments by @dnoeth and @Martin Smith, 
`like '[aeiou]%'` would work in SQL Server (T-SQL extension). However, `regexp` isn't supported in SQL Server. In all other databases from what i know, `like '[aeiou]%'` would match the literal string starting with `'[aeiou]'`.

Comment: Thanks! Is this for all versions of SQL? [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) lists [] as a valid wildcard operator

Comment: @nsledeski As mentioned in the comments above, that's a T-SQL extension.

Comment: No, as mentioned in the comments, the `like '[aeiou]%'` would work in sql server. However, `regexp` isn't supported in sql server. In all other databases from what i know, `like '[aeiou]%'` would match literal string starting with `'[aeiou]'`

Answer (score 1):

I have re-written your regex query this one will work.

as you missed '|' symbol the regex was searching for the exact match "aeiou"

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE city REGEXP '^[a|e|i|o|u]';
```

Answer (score 0):

`like` and `regexp` are quite different.

`like` only recognizes asterisk '%' and '_', while `regexp` use regular expression, which is more powerful.

### Here is a demo:

```
mysql> select 'ixxx' LIKE '[aeiou]', 'ixxx' REGEXP '[aeiou]';
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| 'ixxx' LIKE '[aeiou]' | 'ixxx' REGEXP '[aeiou]' |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
|                     0 |                       1 |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```